# Set cursor at end of textfield in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I have a textfield that may not be able to display its entire contents. When this happens, I'd like to display the right-most contents instead of the left-most contents. Effectively this means I want to set the cursor in the textfield at the right-most position so the contents automatically move in.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange([[textView string] length], 0);
[textView setSelectedRange: range];
```

I'm assuming on OS X because of the tag.

Look to [here for more `NSTextView` quickies](http://borkware.com/quickies/one?topic=NSTextView).

Comment: Correct - this is OS X. Unfortunately I'm getting this error: [NSTextField moveToEndOfLine:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance .  I tried [textField moveToEndOfLine:self] and also [self.textField moveToEndOfLine:self]. Any ideas?

Comment: that seems to work for a textview but I have a textfield. Is my scenario supported or do I need to replace my textfields with textviews?

Comment: Are you want to do like this..... "textField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;"